# Почему нужно каждый раз заново подключаться к базе данных?

Tags: c#, база-данных, sqlite

Например, у меня есть метод

```
public static bool SetNameUser(string oldUsername, string newUsername)
    { 
        ResetConnections();

        Users.dbConnection.Open();
        int number;
        using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(Users.dbConnection))
        {
            command.CommandText =
                $@"Update Users set Username = '{newUsername}' 
                    where Username = '{oldUsername
                    }'";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            number              = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        Users.dbConnection.Close();

        return number is 1;

    }
```

В ResetConnections делается `Dispose` и заново создается подключение.

Есть еще множество подобных, все начинаются с `connection.Open()` и заканчиваются `connection.Close()`
Если я не вызову `ResetConnections()`, то у строка number = ... будет крашиться с ошибкой "Database is locked". 
Если я в каждом методе пересоздаю подключение, то все ок. Простое Open-Close не помогает. Я не пойму, зачем каждый раз пересоздавать подключение? Логично же просто открывать и закрывать его, нет?

База данных Sqlite.
ResetConnections:

```
dbConnection.Dispose()
string baseName = @"Databases\Users.db3";

SQLiteFactory factory = 
DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SQLite") as SQLiteFactory;
dbConnection = factory.CreateConnection() as SQLiteConnection;
dbConnection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source = " + baseName;
```

Comment: Покажите код `ResetConnections`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SqliteConnection`, как и другие `IDbConnection` классы в ADO.NET - это одноразовые обертки над реальным соединением. Их нельзя держать открытыми долго, они не умеют восстанавливаться после ошибок, у них проблемы при работе с одним объектом из разных потоков и прочее.

Создавайте объект connection на время операции, и разрушайте в конце (или явным вызовом `Dispose`, или косвенным, через using):

```
public static bool SetNameUser(string oldUsername, string newUsername)
{ 
    using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(...))
    {
        int number;
        using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(connection))
        {
            // не подставляйте параметры к текст запроса, иначе поймаете иньекцию!
            command.CommandText =
                $@"Update Users set Username = @newUsername 
                   where Username = @oldUsername"; 
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newUsername", newUsername);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldUsername", oldUsername);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            number              = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        return number is 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том что работа с базой данных, по сути является асинхронной операцией выполняемой на стороне сервера, даже после отсылки вам ответа сервер может продолжать обрабатывать ваш запрос (например в нем могут сработать триггеры), это к примеру. Обычно, асинхронность у серверов реализована хорошо, и если вы делаете разные соединения то запросы конфликтовать, в большинстве случаев, не должны. Но вот внутри одного соединения, может быть разное... Это все, если можно так выразится, в общем.

Теперь, конкретней о `sqlite`. Это легонькая файловая база данных, находящаяся прямо в каталоге вашей программы. Скорее всего всех ужасов, что я описал выше, вы никогда не встретите, и это никогда будет продолжаться до тех пор, пока ваше приложение не перерастет `sqlite` и вам не придется менять ее на что то серверное.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее всего вы дважды подряд пытаетесь вызвать метод Open, поэтому и возникает ошибка. Сделайте как в ответе ниже.

Comment: Нет. Когда я пытался открыть уже открытое соединение, я получал ошибку с текстом вроде этого: "Невозможно выполнить команду из-за текущего состояния объекта"