# какой способ работы с базой данных accdb лучше

Tags: c#, база-данных

Работа с базой accdb происходит через клиент на C#
Какой вариант оптимальный? Запросы не будут сверх частыми, мб 1-2 в минуту
1. Открыть соединение с базой при старте программы и закрыть при выходе
2. Открывать/закрывать соединение при каждом запросе CRUD

Comment: Лучше 2. + все методы реализующие CRUD должны быть асинхронными.

Comment: А лучше выбрать другую, нормальную БД

Comment: @АндрейNOP например?

Comment: Да хоть SQLite.

Comment: @АндрейNOP мне нужно чтобы был 1 файл и он при каждом изменении бэкапился на яндексдиск. sqlite позволяет так?

Comment: Позволяет, как и любая другая встраиваемая БД. Но это не относится к вопросу. Ответ на вопрос — берите вариант 2, первый плох: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/827655/218063